# I Want to move data from one TabBar to Another TabBar from Removing it previous position in Flutter By usin Sqllite Database

Tags: flutter, sqlite, tabbar

How to implement this logic that I'm adding data in one list after pressing done button it will erase from one tab and move in another tabbar in flutter

Comment: You can implement Provider, or some state management solution to handle data globaly.

Comment: Yes state management is probably what you are looking for.  There are many approaches for that. Had the same issue and solved it using [scoped_model](https://pub.dev/packages/scoped_model).

Answer (score 0):

So here the Logic
-> Make the Class `Statefull`
-> First you have to Initialise a Global List for that class.
-> Initialise `Bool isForFirstTable = true;`

```
class _SoundSearchState extends State<SoundSearch> {
    List<String> myList = ["radodom","data"];
    bool isForFirstTab= true;
    

    onButtonPressed()
    {
       setState((){
         isForFirstTab = false;
       });
    }


    // and in build tabBar view when you are presenting the tlist.
   // just use the if conditon for that widget
   
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
         return isForFirstTab  
               ? loadingWidget()
              : WidgetList(myList);
      }
}
```